# How to define EF Code First attribute with multiple values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I just developing a personal project and actually I'm using EF Code First from database and I'm facing a little problem.

The problem simply is I want to define an attribute called `Download` and this attribute may contain multiple download links for example :

Attribute Name : Download 
=>Values : 
link1.com
link2.com
link3.com

How to define this in my model an attribute that can hold many values and how can I show them in my view one by one like `foreach` or something to fetch the attribute values and split them

Thanks and I hope someone help me with that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use a single string with a separator, or create another table linked to this one:

```
class Download
{
   ...
   public string Link {get;set;}
}

class ParentClass
{
   ...
   public virtual ICollection<Download> Links {get;set;}
}
```

Then in your view, you can iterate over the list of `Links`.